# React: Stateless component triggers both OnClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following directory structure:

Todo -> TodoList -> TodoItem

I pass todos, onSelection, onDeletion function from todo towards the list and so on to the item.

Both the list and item components are stateless, the issue is that, when I click the item, it fires `onClick()` as well as `onSelect()` method too due to bubbling, I don't want to use event.stopProppogation in any case.

I've also tried the method in stateless component as following but it fires up when the component is loaded.

TodoItem:

```
const TodoItem = ({text, onSelection, onDeletion, id}) => {

  const wrapDeletion = (id) => {
    onDeletion(id);
  }
  return (
    <li className="list-group-item" onClick={onSelection.bind(this, id)}>
      {text}
      <button className="btn btn-danger float-right" onClick={wrapDeletion(id)}>
        {BTN_ACTIONS.DELETE}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Todo List:

```
  <ul className="list-group">
      {todos.map(todo =>
        <TodoItem
          key={todo.id}
          id={todo.id}
          onSelection={onSelection}
          text={todo.text}
          onDeletion={onDeletion}/>)
      }
    </ul>
```

Todo:

```
 <TodoList
          todos={this.state.todos}
          onSelection={onSelection}
          onDeletion={onDeletion}
        />
```

Comment: the issue is that in item when I click onClick it fires of the onSelect method too due to bubbling,
Kindly explain the line above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should intercept the click event and stop it from propagation. To do so, wrap a div and apply it the stopPropagation like so

```
const TodoItem = ({text, onSelection, onDeletion, id}) => {

  const wrapDeletion = (id) => {
    onDeletion(id);
  }
  return (
    <li className="list-group-item" onClick={onSelection.bind(this, id)}>
      {text}
      <div className="clickinterceptor" onClick={(e) => {
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
       }}>
      <button className="btn btn-danger float-right" onClick={wrapDeletion(id)}>
        {BTN_ACTIONS.DELETE}
      </button>
    </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

The docs for this are here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: the main question is doing it without the stopPropgation thing, an way without it?

Comment: i know no other way to diffentiate the clicks from different elements. didnt read well enough, that you explicitly said w/o stopPropagation(), sorry dude

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure you **aren’t** **calling** the **function** when you pass it to the
>   **component**

You are giving a STRAIGHT CALL to a function, while passing it as a all back. Following is one of the solution, passing the callback as a "function returning the call".

```
const TodoItem = ({text, onSelection, onDeletion, id}) => {

  const wrapDeletion = (id) => {
    onDeletion(id);
  }
  return (
    <li className="list-group-item" onClick={onSelection.bind(this, id)}>
      {text}
      <button className="btn btn-danger float-right" onClick={() => wrapDeletion(id)}>
        {BTN_ACTIONS.DELETE}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

You can further read it here!

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback

Comment: The main part of the question is to stop event bubbling, without using `event.StopPropogation()` if I do this the bubbling will persist.